# Importing MySQL database, error 1064

Tags: mysql

I'm a complete rookie at webpage building and now I'm having some trouble importing my database. I tried to import a fairly large file (gzipped at around 1600 KiB) and I keep getting the following error feed:

#### 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 168

```
INSERT INTO `wp_blc_instances` (`instance_id`, `link_id`, `container_id`, `container_type`, `link_text`, `parser_type`, `container_field`, `link_context`, `raw_url`) VALUES
(2040, 115, 710, 'page', 'example', 'link', 'post_content', '', 'examplelink'),
(2041, 123, 710, 'page', 'example', 'link', 'post_content', '', 'examplelink'),
(2042, 119, 710, 'page', 'example', 'link', 'post_content', '', 'examplelink'),
(2043, 124, 710, 'page', 'example ?', 'link', 'post_content', '', 'example'),
(2044, 125, 710, 'page', 'example', 'link', 'post_content', '', 'examplelink'),
(2045, 115, 710, 'page', 'example', 'link', 'post_content', '', 'examplelink'),
(2046, 126, 710, 'page', 'example', 'link', 'post_content', '', 'http://[...]
```

I would be most grateful if someone could give some tips on how to fix this issue.

Comment: Post the complete Query

Comment: @BerndBuffen It's a list of inserts. You want Althea to post all 1.6 MB of it? I don't think that's going to be useful. Posting line 168 would be a good start though.

Comment: TEst it with increase max_allowed_packet in you /etc/my.cnf or /etc/mysql/my.cnf. don´t forget to restart MariaDB after you have change it.

Comment: Try to remove some values from table list, say there are 1000 rows, fix syntax to insert only 100, and so on until you find the troubling row.